# Need help traversing though my linked list. It works fine if there is only one entree, but not multiples. What do I need to fix?

Tags: c

```
struct movie {
    struct movie* next;
    char name[100];
    int rating;
    genre type;
} *list = NULL;

struct movie* search(struct movie* movie) {
    // CODE HERE
    while (list != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(movie->name, list->name) == 0) {
            movie->rating = list->rating;
            return;
        } else {
            list = list->next;      
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

dont need to post any of the other code`

Comment: Why don't you check for `movie` being NULL? I think it is NULL which causes the segfault

Comment: why are you not returning value in the if branch, while the function has a struct movie* return type?

Comment: 1. list is not a good name for a pointer, to a single item. Sounds like a listhead. Maybe `curr`. You're not returning a value as @CIsForCookies said. 2. strcmp() is not considered safe in general, better to use strcncmp() or strncasecmp() - You should learn to use the variants of calls that use lengths to put bounds on things. A lot of the exploits/hacks/stack overflow, etc.. are due to not doing that.

Comment: You should show more code, because you're not showing us how you construct the list, so we don't know what's in it or what you're setting list to initially.

Comment: Your `while` loop has a `return NULL` at the end. So the loop will never actually loop. It will run once and return NULL.

Comment: Also it would be interesting to know how you insert new items to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your code should be:

```
struct movie* search(struct movie* movie) {
    struct movie *my_list= list;        // use a local variable so not to overwrite the global list root
    while (my_list != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(movie->name, my_list->name) == 0) {
            movie->rating = my_list->rating;
            return movie;   // found
        } else {
            my_list = my_list->next;      
        }
    }
    return NULL;            // not found
}
```

Most of my changes have already been mentioned in the comments to your question.